# How to make tableViewCell Size automatic?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an table viewCell and there is 4 buttons but in some case I am hiding one ore more buttons and how to make the size of table view cell automatic ???
[image]

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionCell")!
     variant1 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
     variant2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
     variant3 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
     variant4 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(4) as! UIButton

    let questionTextView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5) as! UITextView
    questionTextView.text = "\(Questions[indexPath.row].content!), подсказка: \(Questions[indexPath.row].hint!)"
    variant1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant1ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    variant2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant2ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    variant3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant3ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    variant4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant4ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    //cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.65)

    let numberOfVars = numberOfVariants[indexPath.row]
    if (numberOfVars == 2) {
        variant1.setTitle(Variants[0+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
        variant2.setTitle(Variants[1+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
        variant3.isHidden = true
        variant4.isHidden = true
    }
    else if (numberOfVars == 3){
        variant1.setTitle(Variants[0+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
        variant2.setTitle(Variants[1+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
        variant3.setTitle(Variants[2+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
        variant4.isHidden = true
    }
    else if (numberOfVars == 4) {
        variant1.setTitle(Variants[0+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
        variant2.setTitle(Variants[1+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
        variant3.setTitle(Variants[2+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
        variant4.setTitle(Variants[3+amaunty[indexPath.row]].title, for: .normal)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: is this cells are designed as Static cells in storyboard or dynamic cells?

Comment: Add height constraint on buttons and create outlets for the constraints.If you want to hide a button just set its height to 0 using its corresponding height constraint outlet.Follow this tut also if you need more help https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: Use StackView in cell and make table view cell height dynamic.  stack view will manage height automatically when you hide buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a UIStackView in UITableViewCell.
In stackview add your buttons and give all four constraints to stackview don't give fix height width.
Now in a cell for row index hide your any of the buttons according to your condition.

**This code is for dynamic height of UITableViewCell.**

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCell

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 1:
        cell.btn1.isHidden = true
        break
    case 2:
        cell.btn2.isHidden = true
        break
    case 3:
        cell.btn3.isHidden = true
        cell.btn2.isHidden = true
        break
    case 4:
        cell.btn4.isHidden = true
        cell.btn3.isHidden = true
        cell.btn2.isHidden = true
        break
    default:
        print("Default")
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
}
```

**First Screenshot shows you the properties of stackview control.**

[image]

**Second screenshot shows you the all four constraint given to the stackview and give height constraint to the all buttons.**

[image]

**Final Response**

[image]

***Thank You***

Answer (score 0):

Using buttons like this will increase complexity. There are far too many possibilities to manage.

Option 1:
Make button a different cell. Each question will be one section in TableView

Option 2:
Use UITableView instead of buttons.
TableView's height will be dynamic and you won't have to manage for different conditions.